# Adding multiple elements to DOM before reflow with JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

Is it possible to add multiple elements to the DOM, and have the browser do a single reflow/repaint after they're all added? I'm following this guy's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11623546/512652), but the elements need to be added at various places throughout the page.

For example,

```
<div>
   <div id="A">
      <p>stuff...</p>
   </div>

   <div id="B">
      <p>stuff...</p>
   </div>

   ...
</div>
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
$("#A").append('<img src="a.png"/>);
$("#B").append('<img src="b.png"/>);
...
```

.. and have the browser wait to reflow/repaint after the last image is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull a clone of the parent element into memory, alter it, and write it all back out at once using [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith):

```
$p = $('#A').parent(); // or select it any way you like
$pc = $p.clone();
$pc.find('#A').append('<img src="a.png"/>');
$pc.find('#B').append('<img src="b.png"/>');
$p.replaceWith($pc);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/fSnLb/