# In the Chrome Dev Tools Timeline, what causes Recalculate Style events that have no stack?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was having an issue with Chromium redrawing a page, and I noticed in the timeline that Recalculate Style was firing at what I think is a really high rate:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Timeline example]

Note that this event is firing at this rate (5000 or so per 30 seconds) the whole time the page is open--idle or not. I'm curious if this is normal, but my question is:

What causes/fires events that the Chrome Timeline doesn't display a stack for?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623299/what-does-recalculate-layout-paint-mean-in-chrome-developer-tool-timeline-record) is related, but not exactly the answer I'm looking for because I know what Recalculate Style means, I just don't know what is causing it.

Comment: Could you please share a page that causes such a behavior?

Comment: I could but it's a massive Webapp. I'm sure that I can track down the issue myself, but I'm more interested in the question posed.

Comment: Which chromium version do you run, and if it's canary, then do you observe the same behavior in Stable? This might be related to the recent [devtools bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=315885)